# Query to get multiple row into single row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have a table in which following information are there:

```
ITEM  WH  BATCH  DOC NO
CLD1  FN   B1      3
CLD1  FN   B1      3
CLD1  FN   B2      3
CLD1  FN   B2      3
CLD1  FN   B3      3
CLD1  FN   B4      3
```

This is the code which I have used to bring the above values:

```
select T0.item,t0.wh,t0.batchnum from oibt t0 where t0.DOCNO = '3' and t0.Wh = 'FN'
```

I need the output like this:

```
ITEM  WH  BATCH
CLD1  FN   B1,B2,B3,B4
```

I have used STUFF & For XML coding too but I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: share your attempts code

Comment: ```select T0.Item,T0.Wh,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + T0.Batch
    FROM OIBT US
   WHERE US.DOCNUM = '3' AND US.Wh = 'FN' 
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [BATCH REF NO] from OIBT T0 
 WHERE T0.DOCNO = '3' AND T0.WH = 'FN' 

 GROUP BY T0.ITEM,T0.WH,t0.Batch
  ORDER BY T0.Item```

Comment: @APDP include your code with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT ITEM
    ,WH
    ,BATCH = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + BATCH FROM table1 t WHERE t.ITEM = ITEM FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
FROM table1
GROUP BY ITEM, WH
```

Updated as per your code sample,

```
SELECT T0.Item
    ,T0.Wh
    ,[BATCH REF NO]  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '; ' + US.Batch FROM OIBT US WHERE US.DOCNO = '3' AND US.Wh = Wh AND US.ITEM = ITEM FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM OIBT T0 
WHERE T0.DOCNO = '3' AND T0.WH = 'FN' 
GROUP BY T0.ITEM,T0.WH ORDER BY T0.Item
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ITEM, 
       WH, 
       BATCH = STUFF((SELECT ',' + BATCH
                      FROM oibt
                      WHERE [DOC NO] = '3'
                      GROUP BY BATCH
                      FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM oibt
GROUP BY ITEM, WH
```

Comment: This solution is amazing  and powerful. I worked for a few days trying to solve this logical problem giving up multiple times, where you have a two sets and you need to choose one of the grouped sets by precedence. Thank you so much, so much more elegant!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher version, you can make use of STRING_AGG built in function without having to do the tedious traditional combination of XML FOR and STUFF:

```
SELECT  ITEM
        ,WH
        ,BATCH = STRING_AGG(BATCH,',')
FROM
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
            ITEM, WH, BATCH
    FROM    OIBT O
    WHERE   DOCNO = '3' 
    AND     Wh = 'FN'
) IQ
GROUP   BY ITEM, WH
```

Comment: Most places I've read say Sql Server 2017 or higher?

Comment: And I can confirm that the function is present on my version of SQL Server 2016