# How to concat distinct values over multiple columns in MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, distinct

I have a table like this

| id | type 1 | type 2 | type 3 | type 4 | type 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | b | not available | not available |
| 2 | c | c | a | not available | not available |
| 3 | not available | not available | not available | not available | not available |

What query will help me get a concat on distinct values in these columns and also rid of the "not available", ie:

| id | types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b |
| 2 | c, a |
| 3 |  |

Comment: Unpivot and then pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY

```
select
  id,
  string_agg(s.tp, ',') as types
from t
cross apply (
  select type1 union 
  select type2 union
  select type3 union
  select type4 union
  select type5  
) s(tp)
group by id
order by id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b9c78a311c106bc768d1c515391ffcc)

Comment: I get the error: 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Sql server supports string_agg since 2017. For earlier version you can use FOR XML subquery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964200/query-to-get-multiple-row-into-single-row for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `not available` means null, you can do:

```
select
  x.id,
  group_concat(distinct t) as types
from (select id from t) x
left join (
  select id, type1 as t from t
  union all select id, type2 from t
  union all select id, type3 from t
  union all select id, type4 from t
  union all select id, type5 from t
) y on y.id = x.id
group by x.id
order by x.id
```

Result:

Result:

```
 id  types 
 --- ----- 
 1   a,b   
 2   a,c   
 3
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01388f6f4c48f544c7530fefafdbd64b).

Comment: @TheImpaler I get the error: ''group_concat' is not a recognized aggregate function'.

Comment: @aquamad96 Do you use MySQL really? The error message looks like MS SQL (Sql Server) one.. check `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina yes thank you I am a mistaken idiot...