# Alternate approach to STRING_AGG with multiple table JOINS (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

**CONTEXT**

I am working with SQL Server 2016. I am trying to group by User table's `id` and `username` and get the `roleDesc` from Role table, as comma separated values.

- The `#userTable` and `#roleTable` tables are mapped by `#mapTable`.
- One user can have multiple roles

Required result:

| id | username | roleDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | role1,role2 |
| 2 | user1 | role2 |

**Issue**

As I am using SQL Server 2016, I am unable to use `STRING_AGG` to group the `roleDesc` into comma separated values.

**My attempt**

I tried using `STUFF`, but get an error.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#userTable') IS NOT NULL) 
    DROP TABLE #userTable

CREATE TABLE #userTable
(
    id int, 
    username nvarchar(200)
) 

INSERT INTO #userTable 
VALUES (1, 'user1'), 
       (2, 'user2') 
   
IF (OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#roleTable') IS NOT NULL) 
    DROP TABLE #roleTable

CREATE TABLE #roleTable
(
    id int, 
    roleDesc nvarchar(200)
) 

INSERT INTO #roleTable 
VALUES (1, 'role1'), 
       (2, 'role2'), 
       (3, 'role3') 
  
IF(OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#mapTable') IS NOT NULL) 
    DROP TABLE #mapTable

CREATE TABLE #mapTable
(
    id int, 
    map_userId int, 
    map_roleId int
) 

INSERT INTO #mapTable 
VALUES (1, 1, 1), 
       (2, 1, 2), 
       (3, 2, 2)
  
SELECT 
    U.id, 
    U.username,
    -- STRING_AGG(R.roleDesc,',')  roleDesc --> this works in SQL Server 2017
    STUFF ((SELECT 
                ',' + R.roleDesc 
            FROM 
                #roleTable T
            WHERE 
                T.id = R.id 
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS roleDesc 
FROM 
    #userTable U
JOIN 
    #mapTable MAP ON MAP.map_userId = U.id
JOIN 
    #roleTable R ON R.id = MAP.map_roleId
GROUP BY 
    U.id,  U.username
```

Links I referred to:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348687/7067740

   - The `where` clause Id inside the `STUFF` is ultimately used in the outer query `GROUP BY`. This is not true in my case.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964302/7067740

   - This is closer to my required solution, but the the `STUFF` query has a simpler `WHERE` clause. I am not able to translate it to my case.

I get this error:

> Column '#roleTable.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**Question**

What could be the alternate approach?

Comment: *What could be the alternate approach* - upgrade to SQL Server 2017+ and use `STRING_AGG` ?

Comment: @marc_s So, is this not possible in SQL server 2016 using `STUFF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `#roleTable` and `#mapTable` on the outer query. Move it to the sub-query

```
SELECT 
    U.id, 
    U.username,
    STUFF ((SELECT 
                ',' + R.roleDesc 
            FROM 
                #roleTable r
            JOIN
                #mapTable m 
            ON
                r.id = m.map_roleId
            WHERE 
                m.map_userId = U.id
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS roleDesc 
FROM 
    #userTable U
GROUP BY 
    U.id,  U.username
```